# compilation error while android project executes

Tags: android

`Here i am using android API(platform-19) and create a project in android eclipse and i install maven plugin version 3.0.5(embedded)  and i create a POM.XML file in the project and given android maven plugin version 3.8.2 but it gives some error.`
Which of the android maven plugin version i need to specify for android API-19.`

`Error is :ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0
[INFO] Manifest merging disabled. Using project manifest only
[INFO] D:\NagarjunaWork\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4.2\aapt.exe [package, -m, -J, D:\26-6-20140929\QuickRideApp\QuickRide\target\generated-sources\r, -M, D:\26-6-20140929\QuickRideApp\QuickRide\AndroidManifest.xml, -S, D:\26-6-20140929\QuickRideApp\QuickRide\res, --auto-add-overlay, -A, D:\26-6-20140929\QuickRideApp\QuickRide\assets, -I, D:\NagarjunaWork\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar]
[INFO] D:\26-6-20140929\QuickRideApp\QuickRide\AndroidManifest.xml:51: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').
[ERROR] Error when generating sources.
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException:`

'can you please help to me.`

Comment: Please post the error.

Comment: Did you solved your problem?